# Capturing LOGIN COOKIE via Rest Template

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, cookies

I have below code for making a POST call to RestAPI for Tableau system, which is working and seeing response output.

However, I would like to capture cookie from this output and need to be used for further consumption! Can somebody help me on this problem?

Code:

```
package com.abc.it.automation.service;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.CookieStore;
import java.net.HttpCookie;
import java.net.URI;
import java.security.KeyManagementException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;

import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.RequestEntity.HeadersBuilder;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.http.client.ClientHttpResponse;
import org.springframework.web.client.ResponseExtractor;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

import com.abc.it.automation.utils.SSLUtil;

public class BIaaSTableauService {



    private static Properties tableau_properties = new Properties();

    static {

        // Loads the values from configuration file into the Properties instance
        try {
            tableau_properties.load(new FileInputStream("res/config.properties"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    private static final String loginURL = tableau_properties.getProperty("server.host");
    private static final String siteSearchURL = tableau_properties.getProperty("site.search.url");



    public static void main(String[] args) throws KeyManagementException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {

        RestTemplate restTableau = new RestTemplate();

        String requestLogin =   "<tsRequest>"+
                            "<credentials name=\"svc_tableau\" password=\"xxxxxxxxx\" >"+
                            "<site contentUrl=\"\"/>"+
                            "</credentials>"+
                            "</tsRequest>";
        SSLUtil.turnOffSslChecking();
        ResponseEntity<String> responseLogin = restTableau.postForEntity(loginURL, requestLogin, String.class);
        System.out.println(responseLogin.getBody());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to build your RestTemplate as follows.

```
RestTemplate restTableau = new RestTemplate(new MyClientHttpRequestFactory());
```

Extend ClientHttpRequestFactory as follows.

```
public class MyClientHttpRequestFactory extends SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory {


private Cookie cookie;
//setters and getters.

@Override
protected void prepareConnection(HttpURLConnection connection, String httpMethod) {
 this.setCookie(connection.getRequestProperty("Cookie"));

}
}
```